# Windows like Restore option in OSX

Tags: macos, backup, restore

Windows provide a facility to restore state of OS in case of getting corrupt by loading it up from Hard drive. Is there anything like that available for OSX?

Answer (score 3):

No, Windows offers different recovery features than OS X.

Particularly Windows is creating automatic (and allowing manual creation of) system [restore points](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378910(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Restore points are created to allow users a choice of previous system states. Each restore point contains the necessary information needed to restore the system to the chosen state. Restore points are created before key changes are made to the system.

These restore points are actual copies of the registry, device drivers, and other configuration and take up disk space on the system drive.

---

With OS X no such system-level backups are taken (or no control over them is given to the user).

Instead Apple takes a different approach in which it protects the core system files and configuration by making them immutable or by observing tough control over their modifications.

SIP (System Integrity Protection) with respect to file system protection in theory ensures that applications and unsigned drivers installed by the user won't mess (either maliciously or through negligence) with the core system configuration so that it will always boot to a good state (and the need for restoring to the last known good state would be eliminated).

---

Either Windows or OS X allow system reinstall without deleting user files.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

The closest thing is [Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250), which will make a snapshot of your system every hour either to your local hard disk or to a nominated backup drive (locally or network attached). Older backups are automatically thinned out; specifically, Time Machine will keep:

- Local backups as space permits
- Hourly backups for the past 24 hours
- Daily backups for the past month
- Weekly backups for all previous months

and it will delete the oldest backup to make room for the newest one, if it has to.

However, Time Machine backups, and the applications used to access those backups, are optimised for restoring either individual files (e.g. in case of accidental deletion or corruption) or your entire system (as one step in the OS X re-installation process). There is no real in-between where you can easily just roll back your system to how it was working a couple of days ago, or to just before you reconfigured something.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, OS X does provide this. To access this you need to hold down the command + R keys when you push the on button to start up your mac, from there you should be able to reinstall, wipe, or restore from backup. Hope this helps you :)

https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201314

Comment: If you made a whats called a  "time machine backup" then you can restore you complete computer to how it was like a few days ago. But if not the only thing you can try is to reinstall the os.